# Update on data which is fetched by a select

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a select which fetches data rows that I want to update:

```
SELECT id, version from list MINUS SELECT id, max(version) OVER (PARTITION BY id) from list
```

Every list from table 'list' has several versions per ID. I want to update the status of every version, which is not the maximum per id.

I tried

```
UPDATE list SET status = '0' WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT id, max(version) OVER (PARTITION BY id)
```

But this obviously did not work (ora-00913 "too many values").

Can somebody help me?

Comment: This sounds like a candidate for using `MERGE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to update the status of every version, which is not the maximum per id.

I would phrase this as:

```
update list l
   set status = 0
    where l.version < (select max(l2.version) from list l2 where l2.id = l.id);
```

This is almost a direct translation of your statement into SQL.

Note:  I removed the single quotes around `0`.  It looks like a number.  If `status` is a number, then don't use a string constant; of course, if `status` is a string, then use the single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I would phrase this update using exists logic:

```sql
UPDATE list l1
SET status = '0'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM list l2 WHERE l2.id = l1.id AND l2.version > l1.version);
```

In plain English, the above update says to assign a status of 0 for every record for which we can find another record of the same `id` which however has a *greater* version than the record being examined.